# node-http-proxy websocket proxying & middleware

Tags: node.js, proxy, websocket

I want to reverse-proxy an existing application which uses websockets, but use application middleware to implement an authorization layer in front of the app.

node-http-proxy advertises both those features, but I can't seem combine them.

Reverse proxying websockets works fine:

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

httpProxy.createProxyServer({  
  target: 'http://127.0.0.1:8888', // where do we want to proxy to?
  ws    : true // proxy websockets as well 
}).listen(3000);
```

When I take a look at the [middleware examples](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/tree/caronte/examples/middleware) though, they all seem to use connect for the server, and at that point the websocket support seems to disappear. eg.

```
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy'),
    connect = require('connect');

var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({
  target: 'http://localhost:8888',
  ws: true
});

connect.createServer(
  connect.compress({
    // Pass to connect.compress() the options
    // that you need, just for show the example
    // we use threshold to 1
    threshold: 1
  }),
  function (req, res) {
    proxy.web(req, res);
  }
).listen(3000);
```

Is this a known limitation, or is there some other way to combine websocket reverse-proxying and middleware?

Comment: Did you manage to figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [http-proxy-middleware](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware) as middleware.
It will proxy http-requests and websockets:

```
var http            = require('http');
var connect         = require('connect');
var proxyMiddleware = require('http-proxy-middleware');

var proxy = proxyMiddleware('http://localhost:8888', {
                changeOrigin: true,   // for vhosted sites
                ws: true
            });

var app = connect();
app.use(proxy);                       // <- add the proxy to connect

var server = http.createServer(app).listen(3000);
```

Checkout the documentation for more configuration options:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-middleware

Comment: consider i am proxying a shiny server which doesn't support  gzip compression . how would i enable compression for it here using http-proxy-middleware ?   i  have a  similar use-case like you have coded

Answer (score -1):

You need to call `proxy.ws()` on the `upgrade` event from the http server.

```
// Listen to the `upgrade` event and proxy the
// WebSocket requests as well.
//
proxyServer.on('upgrade', function (req, socket, head) {
  proxy.ws(req, socket, head);
});
```

see: https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy#proxying-websockets